# Logical equivalences cancellation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given a propositional term, I know we can substitute terms inside it if they are logically equivalent. Now, whenever we simplify propositional terms, whenever there is a term which is always true, i.e $(p \lor \neg p)$, or a term which is always false i.e $(p \land \neg p)$, we can just cancel it from the term. For example, in the term $$(\neg p \lor r)\land((\neg q \land \neg r) \lor (r \land \neg r))$$

We can just remove the term $(r \land \neg r)$. My lecturer justifies this by saying "because it's always $FALSE$", but it doesn't sit right with me. Why is this so? What are we replacing it with that is logically equivalent to it?

Answer (score 4):

Here, you can remove the term $(r \land \neg r)$ because of the $\lor$ operation in the expression $(\neg q \land \neg r) \lor (r \land \neg r)$. Since we know that $(r \land \neg r) = F$ and $F \lor x = x$, we can simply remove the term which is equivalent to $F$ in a situation like this one.

For example if it was $F \land x$, this time, we could have removed $x$ without considering its truth value because $F \land x = F$.

(Note: $F$ stands for $FALSE$ statement, i.e. contradiction. $x$ is any logical expression which has truth value $T$ or $F$)

Answer (score 3):

$p \land \neg p$ is indeed a contradiction, and in logic we use $\bot$ for that, so you can always replace $p \land \neg p$ with $\bot$

However, to completely get rid of a term, you need an equivalence like:

$$p \lor \bot \Leftrightarrow p$$

Please note though that this only works with $\lor$, because in connection with the $\land $ you have:

$$p \land \bot \Leftrightarrow \bot$$

Also, a term like $p \lor \neg p$ is a tautology, and for that we use $\top$.

And some useful equivalences for the $\top$ are:

$$p \land \top \Leftrightarrow p$$

and

$$p \lor \top \Leftrightarrow \top$$

Answer (score 2):

Your text should have a table of "rules of boolean algebra" , "rules of propositional calculus", or such, which contains these rules and more.

$\begin{array}{r|c:c}
\text{Identity} & a\wedge \top = a & a\vee\bot = a\\
\text{Annihilation} & a\wedge\bot = \bot & a\vee\top = \top\\
\text{Complementation} & a\wedge\neg a=\bot & a\vee\neg a =\top\\
\text{Idempotence} & a\wedge a=a & a\vee a=a
\end{array}$

The cancelation, which your professor used, results by combining *complementation and identity* rules.   The pattern happens so often that the middle step is usually skipped over to save time and space.  $$a\vee(b\wedge\neg b)=a\vee\bot=a\\a\wedge(b\vee\neg b)=a\wedge \top = a$$

---

The "top" symbol $\top$ is tautology (or true). $~T$ or $1$ may sometimes be used to represent this *truth constant*.

The "bottom" symbol $\bot$ is contradction (or false). $~F$ or $0$ may sometimes be used to represent this *falsity constant*.